# Docker-compose, host network and reverse proxy

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, host

I have a docker compose on a raspberry pi with some services. I am trying to add a reverse proxy.

One of the services is [home assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/), and it needs to be on the same network as the host because it has some integrations for example with chromecast

To share the network with the host, I use `network_mode: host`, but the reverse proxy cannot find the services.

Here is an example

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command:
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=ro.goab@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/ssl/acme.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      # this host, though not important now will allow traefik
      # to address home assistant later.
      - host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1 
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.mired`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
    network_mode: host
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m


  homeassistant:
    container_name: home-assistant
    image: homeassistant/raspberrypi4-homeassistant:stable
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "10"
    volumes:
      # Data persistency
      - ./hass:/config
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Montevideo
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.homeassistant.rule=Host(`homeassistant.mired`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.homeassistant.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.homeassistant.service=homeassistant"
      - "traefik.http.services.homeassistant.loadbalancer.server.port=8123"
```

If I put the two containers under the same network it works, but home assistant loses the integrations.